# Extract coefficients and t-values from quantile regression, rqpd

Tags: r, coefficients

I have a quantile regression model as follows:

```
rqpdfit <- rqpd(cr1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 +x7|id, 
panel(lambda = 1,taus=c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9),tauw=rep(1/5, 5), method="pfe"),
 data =pdata)
```

To produce output table, I divided results per quantile.

```
cf_10<- summary(rqpdfit)$coefficients[1:8,]
```

Here is the first quantile output:

```
                             Value   Std. Error     t value     Pr(>|t|)                
      (Intercept)[0.1] 14.4864410152 11.670505897  1.24128647 2.145773e-01
    > x1[0.1]          -1.1081682804  1.230039754 -0.90092070 3.676881e-01
    > x2[0.1]           0.5036482698  0.097472484  5.16708152 2.501200e-07
    > x3[0.1]          -0.8077127317  0.282774725 -2.85638234 4.308473e-03
    > x4[0.1]           0.0006560821  0.008695294  0.07545255 9.398587e-01
    > x5[0.1]          -0.0102064486  0.043276674 -0.23584180 8.135683e-01
    > x6[0.1]          -0.1081589250  0.061636404 -1.75478966 7.937665e-02
    > x7[0.1]          -0.7891778648  0.251492587 -3.13797665 1.714334e-03
```

However, I don't know how I can extract coefficients and t-values in matrix (with significance stars if possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the (unnamed) package you are using works with `stargazer`, but otherwise, getting the stars won't be automatic. You usually can extract this info using `summary()`.

```
# coefficients and t-values in matrix
cf_10 <- summary(x)$coefficients[1:8,c(1,3)]
# p-values
cf_10.pVals <- summary(x)$coefficients[1:8,4]
```

If you really want, you could implement an algorithm to paste stars onto the coefficients.

There is likely a prettier way, but this should be fairly straightforward to read:

```
# function to print stars
starPrinter <- function(pVal) {
  if(pVal < 0.01) return("***")
  if(pVal < 0.05) return("**")
  if(pVal < 0.1) return("*")

  return("")
}

# a matrix, with digits rounded to 3rd decimal
myTable <- round(cf_10, 3)
# get stars and put tvalues in parentheses
for(i in 1:nrow(myTable)) {
  myTable[i, 1] <- paste0(myTable[i, 1], starPrinter(cf_10.pVals[i]))
  myTable[i, 2] <- paste0("(", myTable[i, 2], ")")
}
```

If you want to make this a vector, where you have coef1, tval1, coef2, tval2...

```
myEstVector.cf_10 <- as.character(t(myTable))
```

You can then combine multiple results into a new table:

```
myNewTable <- cbind(myEstVector.cf_10, myEstVector.cf_25, myEstVector.cf_99)
```

Comment: Stargazer doesn't support rqpd so it doesn't provide significance stars. Do you have any idea how to create an algorithm?

Comment: Added some code to do this. It's not ideal, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I edited starPrinter and it works now. However, the last line doesn't work (after #get stars.)

Comment: still # get stars part doesn't work. it gives an error `Error in 1:nrow(myTable) : argument of length 0`

Comment: Yes, ls() returns myTable as one of the objects. dim(myTable) is NULL

Comment: `dim(cf_10)  is [1] 8 2`

Comment: `> dim(round(cf_10, 3))  [1] 8 2`  `> dim(as.character(cf_10))
NULL`

Comment: it worked now. I just removed  as.character which messed up myTable. it gave me my stars!!  Thank you so much!

Comment: I try to give you +1 but I don't have 15 point reputation yet.

Comment: not sure but I think, as.character with round is messing the matrix.

Comment: btw do you know how to put t-values under the coefficients in parentheses ?

Comment: @Denis I made some changes in the code above. As I show, the code allows you to post the results of various regressions as in standard tables. As a side note, you were right that as.character was the culprit. I figured out that `as.character` coerces matrices into a vectors.

Comment: @Denis See the last two lines of code in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I just saw the last line of the code. One note is that `myEstVector.cf_10 <- as.character(t(myTable))` where **as.character** messes up significance stars as some variables look like having 5 stars.

Comment: you could try `as.vector()`. If myTable looks fine, then as above, check `t(myTable)`. If that also looks fine, then try `as.vector(t(myTable))`.

Comment: it looks fine now but I lost variable names in the **myNewTable** matrix. It named rows with numbers instead of variable names.

Comment: You can add names using `rownames(myNewTable) <- myNamesVector`. extract the names beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to add to the above thread. I followed the code above and exported results into a csv file format.

```
# y is the dependent variable 
# x6 is a vector of 6 independent variables. 
#setting regression
r6.form <- y ~ x6 |as.factor(cty)
r6090 <- rqpd(r6.form, panel= panel(taus=c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9), tauw = rep(1/5,5)), 
              na.action = 'na.omit', data=mydata)

#Storing results 
c6090 <- summary(r6090, se = "boot", R=1000, covariance = TRUE)

#making a data frame for results
df6 = as.data.frame(c6090$coefficients)

#coefficients and t-values in a matrix
cf_6 <- df6[1:71, c(1,3)]

#p-values
cf_6.pval <- df6[1:71,4]

#function to print stars
starPrinter <- function(pVal) {
  if(pVal < 0.01) return("***")
  if(pVal < 0.05) return("**")
  if(pVal < 0.1) return("*")

  return("")
}

# a matrix, with digits rounded to 3rd decimal
myTable6 <- round(cf_6, 3)

# get stars and put tvalues in parentheses
for(i in 1:nrow(myTable6)) {
  myTable6[i, 1] <- paste0(myTable6[i, 1], starPrinter(cf_6.pval[i]))
  myTable6[i, 2] <- paste0("(", myTable6[i, 2], ")")
}

#creating a vector
table.cf_6 <- (t(myTable6))

#exporting it to CSV file
write.table(table.cf_6, "c6090.csv", sep =',', row.names = TRUE)
```

This extracts results into different columns with variable names.